# How to create an endpoint to upload files in Jersey?

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I want to write a API which will allow me to upload file.
I want to upload log file to my remote location.

In servlet I can get fileName and other details of the file from the request.
Eg :

```java
Part filePart = request.getPart("fileName");
String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
System.out.println(fileName);
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
```

How to do this in REST.

Basically I want to create a endpoint where the user can upload file.
Like Elasticsearch bulk API where I will give the file and its contents are loaded in the server.

Eg :

```bash
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @data.log
```

In my REST API how I will get the contents and meta data of the file to upload to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation to bind the named body part(s) of a `multipart/form-data` request entity body to a resource method parameter, as following:

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    ...
}
```

---

To use multipart features you need to add the [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies (see [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html)) on the classpath. And don't forget to register the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class.

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about multipart requests](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart).

Comment: Hello Sir , Please refer to my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849911/removing-meta-data-from-the-file) and please let me know what I am doing wrong here or what approach should I take. In order to achieve my task.Thank you.